# WL Processing sequence of commands not following the order as programmed

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

WL commands seem to process in their own time aside from the remainder of the running script. So what happens, is that while the WL command is being processed, the script following the command continues to process, which then results into problems, because the logic is processed out of order.

The same thing happens with WL commands between themselves. If you have consecutive WL commands in a certain processing order and therefore requiring to process in that order, the WL commands process simultaineously, but also at their own pace, so you end up having a succeeding WL command processing to completion before a preceeding WL command, result in a logical error of sequence, which obviously is problematic.

Is there an awareness of this problem, and are there any known solutions, because having WL commands processing in their own order of pace or preference, and superseeding consecutive code will just not work well, and result in too many difficulties.

Comment: What's "command"? That's very generic. Edit the question and elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

wl calls are asynchronous calls... you need to chain your code to achive your requirement. example using ".then .else" for JasonStore.